# У меня есть код построения треугольника серпинского, и мне надо дописать код чтоб треугольник заполнялся полностью

Tags: java, алгоритм, android-studio

[image: вот так рисует сейчас]

```
// файл MainActivity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(new Fractal(this));
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int blue = Color.BLUE;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(blue);
    }
}
```

```
    // класс фрактал
    public class Fractal extends View {
    public  Fractal(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        drawTriangle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, 500, 8, canvas);
    }

    protected void drawTriangle(int x, float y, int d, int n, Canvas canvas){
        Paint p = new Paint ();
        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawLine(x - d, y + d, x, y - d, p); // главн
        canvas.drawLine(x + d, y + d, x, y - d, p); // главн
        canvas.drawLine(x - d, y + d , x + d, y + d, p); // главн

        if (n < 2) return;
        drawTriangle(x, y - d / 2 ,d / 2, n - 1, canvas);
        drawTriangle(x - d * 1/2, y + d / 2,d / 2, n - 1, canvas);
        drawTriangle(x + d * 1 / 2, y + d / 2,d / 2, n - 1, canvas);


    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: "чтоб треугольник заполнялся полностью" - ну закрасьте его сплошным цветом.

Comment: ) мне надо чтоб в эти пустоты заполнялись треугольниками

Comment: Какие пустоты? Все? Вы не понимаете смысла понятия "фрактал".

Comment: так в этом и суть задания, что надо переделать код, чтоб заполнять основной треугольник послностью треугольниками

Comment: От того, что Вы еще раз напишeте "заполнять полностью треугольниками", лучше не станет. Вы не поняли (или не смогли передать) "суть задания". Что должно получиться?

Comment: *"мне надо чтоб в эти пустоты заполнялись треугольниками"* — по-моему, вы не очень знакомы с тем, что же такое **фрактал** вообще, и ковер Серпинского в частности...

Comment: с падежами автор тоже "не очень знаком"

Comment: Не нужно удалять содержимое вопроса, оставьте, вдруг кому пригодится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто добавьте рисование четвёртого треугольника вершиной в другую сторону

```
drawTriangle(x, y + d / 2, - d / 2, n - 1, canvas);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но это уже **не треугольник Серпинского**... Так уж проще залить весь треугольник черным цветом — именно это в результате и должно получиться.

Comment: @Harry А автору и не надо Серпинского, нужно на его основе вот такое сотворить, видимо

Comment: Но вы-то понимаете, что в результате такой рекурсии получится просто черный треугольник?...

Comment: Да, разумеется. В приведённом коде есть ограничение рекурсии, можно его оставить, чтобы любоваться красотой неописуемой (как Пеано - заполняющая кривая, а для демонстрации уровень ограничивают)

Comment: Ну, по большому счету, тогда и рекурсия не нужна... (P.S. Если что — минус не мой :))

Comment: @Harry По крайней мере, я только такую логику нашёл подходящей применительно к `надо дописать код чтоб треугольник заполнялся`